# limsup of intersection of events as a subset of intersection of limsups

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ and $B_1, B_2, \ldots$ be two sequences of events in some probability triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P})$. Now, it is true that $\left(\limsup_n A_n\right) \cap \left(\limsup_n B_n\right) \supseteq \limsup_n (A_n \cap B_n)$, and I can think of many different cases where this relation holds true for equality (e.g., let $A_n = B_n$, or $A_n = B_n^c$, or $B_n = \emptyset$, or $B_n = \Omega$). However, I cannot think of any case where $\left(\limsup_n A_n\right) \cap \left(\limsup_n B_n\right) \supset \limsup_n (A_n \cap B_n)$ holds for strict inclusion.

My proof for the relation is simple. Since $A_n \cap B_n \subseteq A_n$ and $A_n \cap B_n \subseteq B_n$, then we can perform some set algebra as follows:

$$\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty (A_k \cap B_k) \subseteq \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$$
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty (A_k \cap B_k) \subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$$

Then we can use the same logic for $B_n$, and come to the conclusion as stated in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take
\begin{align}
\emptyset &\not= A_1 = B_2 = A_3 = B_4 = ...\\
        \emptyset &= B_1 = A_2 = B_3 = A_4 = ...
\end{align}

Comment: Well, that was too easy! Thanks!