# Probability of $\lim \sup$ of intersection

Tags: probability, measure-theory, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf

I'm given two sequences of events $\{A_n\}$ and $\{B_n\}$ with $
\mathbb{P}(\liminf_n A_n) = \mathbb{P}(\limsup_n B_n) = 1$. Can we deduce that $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_n A_n \cap B_n) = 1$?

My attempt was to write 
$$
\mathbb{P}(\liminf_n A_n) = 1 \Rightarrow
\mathbb{P}\left( \left\{ w : \sum_n 1_{A_n}(w) \text{ finite} \right\} \right) = 0
$$
Additionally, we know that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\limsup_n (A_n \cap B_n)) = \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{w : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1_{A_n}(w) \cdot
1_{B_n}(w) =\infty \right\}\right) \\=
\mathbb{P}\left(
\left\{ w : \sum_n 1_{A_n}(w) = \infty, \sum_n 1_{A_n}(w) \cdot 1_{B_n}(w) =
\infty
\right\} \cup \left\{
w : \sum_n 1_{A_n}(w) < \infty, \sum_n 1_{A_n}(w) \cdot 1_{B_n}(w) = \infty
\right\}
\right) \\ = 
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{
   w: \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1_{B_{n_k}}(w) = \infty
\right\}\right) + 0 = \mathbb{P}(\limsup_n B_n) = 1
$$
where in the above we made use of the fact that since $w \in \liminf_n A_n$, the terms in the sum $\sum_n 1_{A_n} 1_{B_n}(w)$ have $1_{A_n} = 0$ for only a finite set of indices. Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Additionally, does this hold when I change the condition of $\mathbb{P}(\liminf_n A_n) = 1$ to $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_n A_n) = 1$? I've been trying to find a counterexample to no avail.

Comment: Consider if e.g. $\mathbb P(A_n\cap B_n)=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Math1000: Could you elaborate a bit? This is a possible counterexample that I had in mind, but wouldn't go forward with because I'm not sure if the condition $\mathbb{P}(\liminf_n A_n) = 1$ allows it.

Comment: That may be the case; I didn't have a specific counterexample in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\{\liminf A_n\} \cap \{\limsup B_n\} \subset \limsup (A_n \cap B_n)$. If two events have probability 1 then their intersection also has probability 1. Hence $P(\{\liminf A_n\} \cap \{\limsup B_n\})=1$ which gives $P\{\limsup (A_n \cap B_n)\}=1$.

Comment: Are you sure the inclusion you wrote is true? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675236/limsup-of-the-intersection-of-two-sets) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231173/limsup-of-intersection-of-events-as-a-subset-of-intersection-of-limsups) seem to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @VHarisop Please check the proof now.

Comment: Here is the proof of the inclusion I have used: if $\omega \in (\liminf A_n) \cap (\limsup B_n)$  then there exists $k$ such that $\omega \in A_n$ for all $n \geq k$ and there exist $n_1<n_2<...$ such that $\omega \in B_{{n_i}}$ for all $i$. It follows that $\omega \in A_{{n_i}} \cap B_{{n_i}}$ fora ll $i$ sufficiently large so $\omega \in \limsup (A_n \cap B_n)$